# Forward chat.[sitename].stackexchange.com to that site's specific chatrooms

Tags: feature-request, chat

There used to be a URL link for `chat.[sitename].stackexchange.com`, which would take you to that site's chatroom  page.

For some reason, this no longer exists. Accessing a specific site's chatrooms is now done through:

```
http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=[sitename].stackexchange.com
```

I'd like to request a forward from `chat.[sitename].stackexchange.com` to the above link, for the convenience of compatability with previous workflows. Also, it's just convenient to be able to type in a URL for a specific site's chatrooms. Otherwise, we have to go to that site, then go through the StackExchange menu to the chat page.

<sup>Yes, yes, I know every change breaks someone's workflow, and all that.</sup>

Comment: I guess those URLs were lost on [the road to SSL](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/).